# Using fork() and execl() in a program to execute other C programs as processes

Tags: c, fork

I am new using both fork() and exec() and I was trying to run three different processes from a C file called Fork.c so that I could execute the code within other three .c files. Each one of those c files would approximate the value of pi using different methods, but that's not important at all.

My main problem is basically not knowing how the execl() works when it comes to C files and I haven't found anything that could clarify my doubts here in stack overflow nor on the internet. So, I would like to make each child compute pi in a different way using the code in those three different files.

By now, what I have in my fork.c is the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < CHILDREN_N; i++)
{
    pid = getpid(); 
    pid = fork(); 

    if (pid == 0) /* child process is always 0 */ 
    { 

        //do something
        printf("I am the child %d and my pid is %d \n", i, getpid());
        execl();
        exit(0); 

    } 

    else if (pid == -1) /*error*/
    {
        printf("Error ocurred.");

        return 0;
    }

    else /* parent process is non-zero (child's pid) */ 
    { 

        fprintf(stdout, "child pid = %d\n", pid); 

        fprintf(stdout, "waiting for child\n"); 

        wait(NULL); 

        fprintf(stdout, "child terminated\n"); 

    } 

    fprintf(stdout, "parent exiting\n"); 


}
```

So, I am not sure how to make that execl() execute the different pi approximation programs as different processes.

Hope I was clear enough and thanks.

Comment: print pid() in the programs that you are starting with excel(). There process id's will be different. This should clarify your problems

Comment: If you want to exec the children, they need to be compiled into standalone executables. Otherwise just link them all into the same program, and call the 3 different functions directly.

Comment: I think I don't get what you are trying to say. I know that each process will have a unique ID but how does that help when it comes to use the execl() with different C files. I am not even sure how I am supposed to make those C files work from the main c file.

Useless, you mean I should compile them and then use execl() on the executables? That makes sense. So I could store the file names in an array and then execute them independently.

Comment: It may help to think of `fork` as a sort of box that you (your process, really, but let's say "you" here) step into that makes a clone of yourself.  The box buzzes with electricity and then, poof, there are two of you, completely identical.  Which one is the "original" and which one is the "clone"?  The box helpfully stamps each of you with a sticker: one says "12345", the other says "0".  The "you" that gets 0 is the clone.  You're still both identical, so you just need to plan, ahead of time, what to do if the box stamps you "0".

Comment: "clarify my doubts" which doubts? You are not naming any. Please explain what exactly is unclear about `execl`.